# Selecting multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that check if the attachment size of the attachment is greater than 10MB. Now, if the attachment is greater than 10MB, it displays the file names on a `msgbox` then I want to select or highlight the cells that has this attachment greater than 10 MB but dunno how to do it.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Function checkAttSize()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim attach As Object
Dim attSize() As String
Dim loc() As String
Dim num As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
lRow = Cells(Rows.count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
efCount = 0
num = 0
With objMail
    If lRow > 22 Then
    On Error GoTo errHandler
        For i = 23 To lRow
            'attach.Add main.Range("O" & i).value
            'totalSize = totalSize +
            If (FileLen(main.Cells(i, "O").value) / 1000000) > 10 Then
                ReDim Preserve attSize(efCount)
                ReDim Preserve loc(num)
                'store file names
                attSize(efCount) = Dir(main.Range("O" & i))
                'store cell address
                loc(num) = i
                efCount = efCount + 1
                num = num + 1
                found = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End With

If found = True Then
    MsgBox "Following File(s) Exceeds 10MB Attachment Size Limit:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Join(attSize, vbCrLf) _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please try removing the file(s) and try again.", vbCritical, "File Size Exceed"
'trying to select the cell addresses
    For i = 1 To num
        rng = rng + main.Range("O" & loc(i)).Select ' Ive also tried &
    Next i
    checkAttSize = True
    Exit Function
End If
Exit Function
errHandler:
MsgBox "Unexpected Error Occured.", vbCritical, "Error"
checkAttSize = True
End Function
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

No need to select the range. A single miss click by the user take take the focus away from the range. Also using `.Select` recklessly may cause run time errors. Color them instead.

After this line

```
If (FileLen(main.Cells(i, "O").value) / 1000000) > 10 Then
```

Add this line

```
main.Cells(i, "O").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

The cells now will be colored in red.

And in the end, alert the user with the message

```
If found = True Then
   MsgBox "File(s) Exceeding 10MB Attachment Size Limit has been colored in red:"
End If
```